# How to setup leaflet map to display a WMS layer in ESRI:102012 projection?

Tags: wms, coordinate-system, leaflet, proj

I have a WMS server that serves layers in ESRI:102012 projection.
http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102012/
It accepts GetMap requests with srs=EPSG:102012 parameter.

My goal is to display a map in this projection with some WMS layers on it.

I'm using a proj4leaflet plugin (https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) to setup a map for this projection, but I'm stuck with defining L.Transformation, scale and resolution parameters.
Can anybody tell me what to put in those parameters, or give a working example of leaflet map in this projection?

Comment: Asia Lambert: proj=lcc +lat_1=30 +lat_2=62 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=105 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

Comment: : I can't tell if the L.transformation has to be the real lower left of the data or can be more general. Try using -77 million, 0 for the lower left bound. If that doesn't work, try to get the LL from the WMS server. If you can only get it in degrees, let me know and I'll convert it for you. mkennedy at esri dot com

Answer (score 2):

leaflet has proj4 support

you should take a look at this [1] and here is a small example [2]

Hope this helps

[1] https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/

[2] https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/blob/master/examples/index.html